# Applying Hahn-Banach to space of polynomials?

Tags: functional-analysis

Does $\phi$ extend to a bounded linear functional on $L^2([0,1]),$ where $\phi$ is defined on the space of polynomials, $\mathcal{P}$, on $[0, 1]$ and $\phi(f)=f(1/2)?$ Prove or disprove.

Few questions:

1. Is there a sound strategy to approach such open-ended questions (i.e. provide a proof or disproof)?
2. I know that $\overline{\mathcal{P}[0,1]} = \overline{C([0,1])}$ under the supremum norm, and $\overline{C([0,1])}= L^2([0,1])$ under the $L^2$-norm, so I think the answer is affirmative (using Hahn-Banach). Am I on the right track?

Hope someone can shed insight.

Comment: $L^2([0,1])$ is not endowed with the supremum norm.

Comment: The members of $L^2[0,1]$ are not functions but equivalence classes of functions.  But  if $P$ is a polynomial on $[0,1]$ then the  equivalence class $[P]$ contains no polynomials other than $P,$ so you can make $\phi$ well-defined on the equivalence classes of polynomials. However , as pointed out in the Answer below, $\phi$ is not bounded with respect to the  $L^2$ norm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order that you can extend $\phi$ to a  continuous linear functional on $L^{2}[0,1]$ it has to be a continuous linear functional on the space of polynomials with $L^{2}$ norm. If this is so then there is a finite constant $C$ such that $|f(\frac 1 2 )| \leq C\|f\|_2$. If this holds for polynomials it must hold for continuous functions (an easy consequence of Weierstrass approximation). However, it is easy to construct continuous functions $f$ with $f(\frac 1 2 )=1$ and $\|f\|_2$ arbitrarily small by making $f$ small outside a neighborhood of $\frac 1  2$ so $\phi $ is not a bounded linear functional to begin with.

Comment: Could you clarify the "easy" part - an example of such a continuous function? In general, what is the procedure to construct a continuous function with arbitrarily small $L^p$ norm?

Comment: If $f(\frac 1 2)=1$, $f(x)=0$ for $|x-\frac 1 2 | >c$ and $0\leq f \leq 1$ then $\|f\|_2 \leq \sqrt {2c}$ and you can choose $c$ as small as you want.  To construct such a function $f$ just take straight line graphs between $\frac 1 2 -c$ and $\frac 1 2  +c$. Drawing a picture helps.